# Why do Z Fighting overlapping artifacts appear when I paint my character?

Tags: texturing

I made a simple character which is a cube with two arms extruded. That's it very simple. Yet when I paint the character this happens

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe you have overlapping vertices, what does it give if you select all in Edit mode and press M > Merge by Distance? Or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @moonboots literally saved my day THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos how would you describe what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping vertices, what we see is another mesh protruding, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.